# Как перевернуть дек или список за O(1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, список, сложность

Дали задание перевернуть список или дек за O(1).
Точнее, сказано было, что надо перевернуть, не переворачивая буквально...
То есть `Reverse`, `reversed` и `[::-1]` нельзя, потому что они все O(n).
Как быть?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/pixonic/blog/480462/

Comment: только там с++, а не питон. Мне кажется, что reverse - самое оно. Он прям делает то, что автор и написал: "перевернуть, не переворачивая буквально"

Comment: @KoVadim reverse не проходит временные тесты, увы

Comment: вот с тестов думаю и нужно было начать

Comment: классический двусвязный список + флаг направление обхода? `def reverse(self): self._dir = not self._dir`

Comment: 1) Пишете 2 связный список 2) Делаете методы в нем для прямого и обратного прохода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, вот таким образом все тесты прошлись в итоге

```
from collections import deque
 
class FlipList:
    def __init__(self):
      self.list = deque() 
      self.reverse = False
 
    def push_last(self,x):
      if self.reverse:
        self.list.appendleft(x) 
      else: 
        self.list.append(x) 
 
    def push_first(self,x):
      if self.reverse:
        self.list.append(x) 
      else:
        self.list.appendleft(x) 
      
    def pop_last(self):
      if self.reverse:
        temp = self.list[0]
        self.list.popleft()
      else:
        temp = self.list[len(self.list)-1]
        self.list.pop()
      return temp
      
    def pop_first(self):
      if self.reverse:
        temp = self.list[len(self.list)-1]
        self.list.pop()
      else:
        temp = self.list[0]
        self.list.popleft()
      return temp
 
    def print(self):
      print("=======")
      for i in range(len(self.list)):
        print("list value", self.list[i])
      print("=======")
      
    def flip(self):
      if self.reverse:
        self.reverse = False
      else:
        self.reverse = True
```

Answer (score 7):

Встроенный список переворачивается за примерно константное время (при наличии свободной памяти для объекта итератора).  Пруф: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b96370030707b68e8a5b787e933654297ddbc98/Objects/listobject.c#L3293

Код:

```
data = list(range(1000))
target = reversed(data)
```

Эксперимент:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> l = list(range(10**3)); timeit(lambda: reversed(l), number=10**8)
40.847215030982625
>>> l = list(range(10**4)); timeit(lambda: reversed(l), number=10**8)
40.47011766099604
>>> l = list(range(10**5)); timeit(lambda: reversed(l), number=10**8)
40.52599230996566
>>> l = list(range(10**6)); timeit(lambda: reversed(l), number=10**8)
40.59144256397849
>>> l = list(range(10**7)); timeit(lambda: reversed(l), number=10**8)
40.43627246998949
>>> len(l)
10000000
>>>
```

Как видите, на моём ноутбуке любой список переворачивается сто мильонов раз подряд за 40 секунд *независимо* от его длины.

---

Обратите внимание, встроенная функция [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) не выполняет буквального разворота списка и вообще никак его не изменяет и даже не копирует. Она только лишь возвращает специальный объект-итератор, который позволяет просмотреть список в обратном направлении. Если исходный список модифицировать как-то помимо переворачивающего итератора, то это отразится и на перевёрнутый вид.

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> r = reversed(l)
>>> l[3] = 42
>>> print(*l); print(*r)
0 1 2 42 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 42 2 1 0
```

А вот вариант со срезом `[::-1]`, предлагаемый топикстартером, хоть и переворачивает список, но приводит к фактическому копированию исходного экземпляра. На что требуется каждый раз выделять новую память и выполнять линейный обход этого списка.

Answer (score 2):

Написать свой список-обертку, который пересчитывает индекс внутри `get`.

```
reversed_list = ReversedList(old_list) # O(1)
```

Comment: Идея хороша, тока [[tag:python]] ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Не-е-е, бензин Ваш, идеи наши.

Comment: Ну хоть: `reversed_list = ReversedList(old_list) # O(1)` ?